# Jasmine spy "expect(xxx).notToHaveBeenCalled()

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jasmine

With great thanks to those that so swiftly rescued me. The essence of the problem was that I failed to realize I should be looking in documentation for "matchers", and looking in "expect" was not going to solve my problem.

I'm working with Jasmine 3.0 (and very new to it!) and trying to verify that a spy sees zero calls to a target under particular conditions. I thought I might use the `count()` behavior for this, but I'm struggling to work out what syntax I should use.

I've tried

```
spyOn(target, 'action').and.callThrough();
target.triggeringAction();
expect(target.action).count().toBe(0);
```

But Jasmine reports `TypeError: expect(...).count is not a function`.
I don't see any `expect(...).toNotHaveBeenCalled()` and I'm not sure where to look next.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `expect(target.action).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(0);`

Comment: Ah, so what I now know is that the thing I was missing was that these functions are "matchers". I was looking in the docs for expect() :( Appreciate your effort

Answer (score 1):

This could work as well `expect(target.action).not.toHaveBeenCalled();`

Comment: Ah, so what I now know is that the thing I was missing was that these functions are "matchers". I was looking in the docs for expect() :( Appreciate your effort